# Styling lists with natural behaviour

Tags: css

I want to style a css list like this

```
[ 1 ][ 2 ]
[ 3 ][ 4 ]
[ 5 ][ 6 ]
```

Which is basically no problem when using float:left
But there is a problem, when [ 4 ] is heiger than 3 the following happens:

```
[ 1 ][ 2 ]
[ 3 ][ 4 ]
     [   ]
[ 5 ][ 6 ]
```

But i want to behave it like this:

```
[ 1 ][ 2 ]
[ 3 ][ 4 ]
[ 5 ][   ]
[ 7 ][ 6 ]
```

Please take a look at the problem:
http://xbox360livegold.nl/gastenboek

Comment: Best part of my morning so far: watching old folks pretend to play video games.

Comment: shouldn't 6 and 7 be the other way around in your last example?

Comment: @oezi: I don't think so. He's keeping odd-numbered items in the left column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do this in pure CSS unless you know ahead of time what each item is going to look like, and I'm assuming this is for the news feed section on the site you lined to. You might be able to use something like the [JQuery Masonry library](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry/) to accomplish it.

Comment: The jQuery Masonry library looks like what i need :-) Pure CSS would be better tough.

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with the items being displayed from top to bottom instead of left to right, i.e. like this:

```
[ 1 ][ 4 ]
[ 2 ][   ]
[ 3 ][ 5 ]
```

then you could use the [CSS3 multi-column feature](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multicolumn.html). Setting the column-count to 2 will automatically divide the items into two columns.

Comment: They have to be in chronological order so its not possible to show them from top to bottom.

Comment: @Morgen32: Then I guess you'll have to go with the other answer (Masonry). I don't think it's possible using pure CSS.